# How to connect an android application to a self-hosted Parse.com server?

Tags: android, mongodb, parse-platform, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon EC2 Ubuntu instance with MongoDB, Node.JS and Parse Server Example from [GitHub project](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example).

I have migrated my Parse.com to MongoDB on the instance. It's address is `mongodb://usr:****@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017/euro`.

I've installed the Parse Server Example from GitHub in `/var/www/parse`.

When I run the server, I get this message:

```
$ cd /var/www/parse
$ npm run start

> parse-server-example@1.4.0 start /var/www/parse
> node index.js

DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.
parse-server-example running on port 1337.
Parse LiveQuery Server starts running.
```

My question is what points to `localhost`? Public DNS? Public IP?

How can I connect to the server using this code in an android app?

```
Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(myContext)
    .applicationId("YOUR_APP_ID")
    .server("http://YOUR_PARSE_SERVER:1337/parse")
    .build()
);
```

When I tried to open it through browser using this address `http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-x.amazonaws.com:1337/parse` (Public DNS) I got a message saying that the connection had stopped.

When i tried to open it through browser using this address `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1337/parse` (Public IP) I got a message saying that the connection had stopped.

Comment: Open the port in your security group?

Comment: Yes, I did open the port

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` is a alias for `127.0.0.1`. This is your address for `loopback`.
It's only accessible locally.

[localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) on Wikipedia

Comment: My question is how can I point to this address from a computer that isn't on the same network.

Comment: You can't, it's `locahost`. But your server is listening to your computer address IP. The warning only tell you that it's connecting to MongoDB on `localhost`.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. The localhost is on the EC2 instance. I want to know how can I point to this address from my computer.

Comment: You have to find the address IP of DNS entry for your EC2 istance. I don't know how amazon work this that. Sorry!